# CBV классы и получение объектов

Tags: django

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше сделать.

Есть модели.

- `Thema` - первичная
- и `Comment` - вторичная по `ForeignKey`.

Есть `url`, по которому `ListView` выводит список тем, далее есть `DetailView`, где информация по определенной теме, в том числе, все комментарии по этой теме. Тут все работает.

Затем хочу сделать отдельный `url` с добавлением комментария с помощью `CreateView`.

Вопрос такой: Как в методе `form_valid()` получить объект `Thema`, связанный с комментарием, который я делаю?

```
Thema.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['thema_slug'])
```

Это не работает. `kwargs` пустой. Как-то нужно в `form_valid` получить доступ к слагу темы.

Comment: Сообразил. Нужно в новый url с CreateView тоже прописать слаг и тогда в kwargs появится доступ.